# iTunes Connect - Export Compliance is necessary for password?

Tags: ios, encryption, app-store-connect

I am submitting my app in the Apple store and using AES encryption for passwords with the CryptoSwift library. Should I answer "Yes" or "No" to the following question?

> Export Compliance
>
> Is your app designed to use cryptography or does it contain or
>   incorporate cryptography? (Select Yes even if your app is only
>   utilizing the encryption available in iOS or OS X.)

And if so, what precise report or information do I need to provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: NO

Encryption and cryptography are [different things](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/enterprise-security/articles/65254.aspx) (more source available on google)